# OpenGL multihead vsync with different refresh rates

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl

How do I drive multiple displays (multihead) at different resolutions and refresh rates with OpenGL (on Windows 7) and still be able to share textures between the devices?

I have one multi-head gpu.  It drives 4 heads.  (It happens to be an AMD FirePro V7900 in case it matters.)  The heads all share a "scene" (vertex and texture data, etc.), but I want render this scene each time a vsync occurs on the display (each head is essentially a different viewport).  But the catch is that the different heads may be at different refresh rates.  For example, some displays may be at 60Hz and some may be at 30Hz and some may be at 24Hz.

When I call `SwapBuffers` the call blocks, so I can't tell which head needs to be rendered to next.  I was hoping for something like Direct3D9's `IDirect3DSwapChain9::Present` with `D3DPRESENT_DONOTWAIT` flag, and the associated `D3DERR_WASSTILLDRAWING` return value.  Using that approach, I could determine which head to render to next.  By round-robin polling the different heads until one succeeded.  But I don't know what the equivalent approach is in OpenGL.

I've already discovered `wglSwapIntervalEXT(1)` to use vsync.  And I can switch between HDC's to render to the different windows with a single HGLRC.  But the refresh rate difference is messing me up.

I'm not sure what I can do to have a single HGLRC render all these displays at different refresh rates.  I assume it has to be a single HGLRC to make efficient use of shared textures (and other resources)...correct me if I'm wrong.  It's not interesting to me if the resources are duplicated with multiple HGLRC's because I would expect that would cut my memory down to 25% (4 heads on 1 GPU: so I don't want 4 copies of any resource.)

I'm open to the idea of using multiple threads, if that's what it takes.

Can someone tell me how to structure my main loop so that I can share resources but still drive the displays at their own refresh rates and resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can share OpenGL buffers carrying data by sharing the contexts. The call in Windows is names `wglShareLists`.

Using that you can give each window it's own rendering context running in a own thread, while all of the contexts share their data. Multiple window V-Sync in fact one of the few cases where multithreaded OpenGL makes sense.

Comment: This sounds promising.  I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: I tried this, but what I see is that a texture copy takes N milliseconds with one context, 2*N ms with two contexts, 3*N ms with three contexts, and 4*N ms with four contexts.  This doesn't sound like sharing.  It sounds more like "broadcasting", and it further concerns me that I'm not actually reducing the amount of memory or time that it takes to update one texture that is intended to be shared by each context.  In the spirit of full disclosure, I need dynamic textures (representing a number of video capture sources).  What's the right way to set up the transfers so that memory is shared?

Comment: Perhaps you could also clarify when I call `wglShareLists(hglrcA, hglrcB)` does it matter which context is which (A,B) vs. (B,A)?  Does it form a bidirectional link?  I don't feel like I understand this function yet because it's not doing entirely what I expected.

Comment: @Wyck: The connection is bidirectional once established. At establishing the connection the association is from A to B, hance B should not have any shareable objects (display lists, textures, vertex buffer objects, pixel buffer objects) created when calling wglShareLists. – What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done anything like this before.

Looks like you actaully need multiple threads to get independent refresh rates.

An OpenGL render context can be active in only one thread. One thread can only have one active render context. Therfore with multiple threads you will need multiple render contexts.

It is possible to [share resources](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Platform_specifics%3a_Windows#wglShareLists) between OpenGL contexts. With this it is not necessary to store resources multiple times.

Comment: It's not so much the contexts that is the problem.  To render multiple heads with a single context, you simply select the HDC into the one-and-only context as you render content for each window.  What I do now is something like `wglEnableContext( hdcMonitor[currentMonitor], hglrc )` but it's the `SwapBuffers` call that blocks until resources become available.  If you SwapBuffers on the slow head then you'll be late servicing the faster head. Also it's unknown how to tell when the rates precess against each other because the faster head would need more updates than the slower head.